# How to fix "Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 32]"

Tags: python, pip

When I try to update some package,like pyparsing, by pip in PowerShell, the following code comes out.

```
PS C:\Users\asus> pip install --upgrade pyparsing
Collecting pyparsing
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/e8/6777f6624681c8b9701a8a0a5654f3 eb56919a01a78e12bf3c73f5a3c714/pyparsing-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 32]Another program is using this file and the process is inaccessible.: 'C:\\Users\\asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-qscubtdg\\7a9bd1f1a8a0eca5473b1eb452840d768d65705871eba1e389e4693d'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Comment: 1. Try opening PS as administrator (right click start menu button and select "Windows Powershell (Admin)".

2. Try using `--user` option as : `pip install --user dummy`.

Comment: Thank you! But it still can't work after I tried both methods.

Comment: Please try to close all console windows and all python editors then open a command window (cmd) or PowerShell (ps) and try again.

Comment: After I restart my computer, it still can't work.-_-

Answer (score 5):

Please try pip with option: --no-cache-dir

Answer (score 1):

Run the program as an administrator.

In my case I was using eclipse with Pydev. When I open eclipse as admin it worked.

P.S. To run it as admin, just right click and select run as admin.